# Java google cloud endpoint existence query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

How might I write an existence query? Basically I have a datastore "table" with a bunch of data and I want to check if a particular value exists. I imagine checking for "existence", if such a thing exists, would be much faster then querying for everything that matches and then checking if `getResultList().isEmpty()` or such.

I don't mind suggestions in either JPA or Datastore Queries

For a bit more detail. Say one of the fields of my entity is name and I want to find if anyone in my "table" has the name "john". I don't want a list of all Entities with the name="john". I just want to know if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is by running a key-only query which only hits the index and no entity fetch is done.

```
Query query = new Query("SomeKind");
query.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "john"));
query.setKeysOnly();

DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
List<Entity> entities = ds.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));
if(entities.size() == 1) {
    //Exists!
}
```